# "Programming pearls": Column 13 Searching

Tags: search

From Programming Pearls: [Column 12: Searching:](http://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=programming%20pearls%20column%2013&source=bl&ots=DgvTDRAMcv&sig=gWPqGmJ_AIs1TZPzGJ7FtXMCjNk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IkQbUPnpOKP20gGouYCoAg&ved=0CGQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)
There are two code segments:

```
    IntSetList(int maxelements, int maxval)
    {   sentinel = head = new node(maxval, 0);
        n = 0;
    }
    void report(int *v)
    {   int j = 0;
        for (node *p = head; p != sentinel; p = p->next)
            v[j++] = p->val;
    }
```

I'm curious how does the *sentinel* work in the *report* function?

If necessary, please see [the complete source code](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sets.cpp).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sentinel` is just the value that the last pointer in the list is expected to have; it's the value that a `next` member has when it doesn't point to anything. It's initialized to point to the first, "dummy" node in the list; new items are inserted at the beginning, so the sentinel drifts to the end.